# swiftmailer text/plain line breaks?

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am trying to send a message using PHPs mail library called `Swiftmailer`. The problem is that the text is rendered without line breaks and I can't really see the reason for that. I've tried reading the mail using gmail and yahoo.

The code:

```
// [..] bla bla
$message->setBody("a\r\nb", 'text/plain')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML doesn't obey line breaks (they're treated as spaces). You need to use `<br />` tags instead. If you're filling in plaintext dynamically, you can use PHP's `nl2br()` to do this for you.

Comment: Sorry, that had to be `text/plain`.

Comment: Perhaps something's overriding the text/plain setting? What happens if you embed an html tag or two in the message? If it's truly coming out as text/plain, you'd see the raw tag in the email body while reading it.

Comment: I've actually tested the `<br />` tag in `text/plain` and it worked. This of course means that gmail is actually rendering the email not as a `text/plain`. However, this is off-topic to this question. Will create another one. Thank you, @Marc B.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP_EOL 
Example:

```
    ->setBody('Hi Sir/Mam,'.PHP_EOL.'Here is my message.')
```